# Why this swiftUI rectangle is shift to the right?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to draw on the top center of my view a rectangle .. but I can't understand why with this simple code the rectangle is shift to the right when I apply the padding..

```
struct StartContent: View {
    @ObservedObject var dm : DataManager
    @Binding var user : UserModel?
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geo in
            
            VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 10) {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(Color.primary, lineWidth: 2)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 200)
                    
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// see picture:

[image: err]

I want my rectangle stay centered on the view...

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set horizontal padding before frame.

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
    .stroke(Color.primary, lineWidth: 2)
    .padding(.horizontal)// << Here
    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 200)
```

---

or Set size to `VStack`.

```
 VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 10) {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(Color.primary, lineWidth: 2)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 200)
                
                    .padding(.horizontal)
}.frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height) // <<=== Here
```

Comment: U didn't declare geo I have no idea what its mean to be

Comment: @c-sharp-and-swiftui-devni check question. You can get full code